# Computing weight in Julia for Graph construction

Tags: optimization, graph, julia, vertex, computation

Here is the way I implemented my Graph vertices and Edges in Julia for an optimization problem concerning Schedule Recovery

Just concentrate on the two last code functions **empty_graph** and **add_label!**, the other code is just informative about the tools I created in my code.

Port:

```
type VSRPPort
  length::Int32 
  name::String 
  distances::Dict{String,Int32} 
  rates::Dict{String,Int32} 
end
```

Schedule:

```
type VSRPSchedule
  PortList::Array{VSRPPort,1}
  proformaDeparture::Dict{String,Int32}
  callTime::Dict{String,Int32}
end
```

Vessel:

```
type VSRPVessel
  name::String 
  length::Int32
  minSpeed::Int32 
  maxSpeed::Int32  
  startPort::VSRPPort
  startTime::Int32 
  endPort::VSRPPort 
  endTime::Int32 
  schedules::Array{VSRPSchedule,1} 
end
```

**The function that creating an empty graph G:**

```
function empty_graph()
   va=Array{Graphs.ExVertex,1}()
   ea=Array{Graphs.ExEdge{Graphs.ExVertex},1}()
   G = Graphs.graph(va,ea)
   return G
end
```

**and the function fulling the graph of the vertices:**

```
function add_label!(G,s::String, ves::VSRPVessel, p::VSRPPort, time)
   v = Graphs.ExVertex(Graphs.num_vertices(G) + 1,s)
   v.attributes["vessel"]=ves
   v.attributes["port"]=p
   v.attributes["curTime"]=time
   Graphs.add_vertex!(G,v)
end
```

My question concerns the weight associated to the way I created the vertices with its attributes. Is the vertex carrying every Port and Vessel information it has as attributes? Is it going to put a lot of weight in the computation and therefore not being a good move?

Because I also had the idea of just putting an index on every vertex and then for every operation on the Graph, instead of directly accessing the information from the vertex it would have to go through the list of all ports and vessels to find the right one and do the operation.

My problem will be an optimization problem so a large amount of operations on the graph will occur.

So my question is informative, Between these two methods what does it imply in terms of computation ? in terms of optimized coding methods.

I hope my problem description is enough clear. 
Thanks in advance for taking time in answering my several questions.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your questions, but have you considered using MetaGraphs.jl or SimpleWeightedGraphs.jl? Perhaps you have a cleaner solution already implemented for you there.

Comment: This implementation is clear enough for me, with this I can access really quickly and with already implemented functions to all the vertices and edges information. My question was regarding the way Julia is dealing with graph operations.

Comment: I don't think there is a right answer, I just wanted to know if someone had an idea of the relative computation time of each of the two options I had